# Using underscore to sort a collection based on date

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone collection which has a bunch of models with date attributes associated with to them. I want to sort them based on their dates. So the latest dates first and so on.
Whats the best way to go around this.

The dates are formatted like this,  a basic date object. Date {Mon Mar 05 2012 23:30:00 GMT-0500 (EST)}

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have Date objects so you can use [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) to convert them to numbers and then negate those numbers to get the most-recent dates first. If you want to keep your collection sorted then a comparator like this:

```
C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //...
    comparator: function(m) {
        return -m.get('date').getTime();
    }
});
```

will do the trick. Demo (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/htcyh/

Backbone collections also [include](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) Underscore's [`sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) so you could do a one-time sort:

```
var sorted = c.sortBy(function(m) { return -m.get('date').getTime() });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FF5FP/

Or you could use [`toArray`](http://underscorejs.org/#toArray) to get a normal JavaScript array and use the standard [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) without using `getTime`:

```
var sorted = c.toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a.get('date');
    b = b.get('date');
    if(a > b)
        return -1;
    if(a < b)
        return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QRmJ4/

Comment: I like the comparator method very clean and simple. One question I had was is there a way to have sort reversed. So the closer the date is to the current date those would be first and not last like it is using the following.     comparator: function(m) {
        return m.get('date').getTime();
    }

Comment: I just realized thta my dates are not as a date object but as a value of 201203051400 so I presume that's causing the issue. Is there a way of dealing with the string value and still use the same setup or would it be better to turn the value into a date object first and then do the comparator method.

Comment: @Chapsterj: If you have Date objects then you can look at `your_date -  new Date` or `new Date - your_date` as appropriate. If your dates are ISO-8601-ish strings then you can convert them to Dates in the comparator function or you (better IMHO) convert them to Date objects when you load and parse your data.

Comment: using Date.now() you get millis since Jan 1 1970, so that works better than new Date() for most scenarios IMO. so it would just be collection.sortBy(function(model) { return -model.get('date') });

Comment: @AlexMills: I don't see the relevance of `new Date` or `Date.now()` here, AFAIK the collection already contains `Date` instances. Or do you think it is better to rely on the implicit typecast (i.e. applying a numeric operator to a `Date` effectively calls `getTime` first) rather than being explicit about what you're doing?

Comment: I'd say go with Date.now() and be explicit. It's always just an integer behind the scenes anyway. I would only mask it in the user interface. Everywhere else (db, or in runtime program) it doesn't need a mask IMO.

Comment: @AlexMills But they already have `Date`s, why overcomplicate things? Do you also store your timestamps as integers in your databases?

Comment: When it comes down to it, dates are simply integers. But it depends on your db vendor as to how you should store it.

Comment: @AlexMills: When it comes down to it, strings/dates/structs/JavaScript programs/... are simply (large) integers. But only a mad man would work with them like that. If your DB vendor doesn't have date and time types (and a suite of functions and operators that understand their internal structure) then you should set them on fire.

Comment: I have seen people grossly misuse dates by trying to manipulate them as strings and such. I feel like it's more important that people just realize they are integers and shouldn't ever be manipulated any other way. I currently use MongoDB and "BSON (the storage data format used by mongo natively) has a dedicated date type UTC datetime which is a 64 bit (so, 8 byte) signed integer denoting milliseconds since Unix time epoch."

Comment: @AlexMills: Sorry but I gotta' call that nonsense. There are so many nasty complexities in date and time handling that doing it all yourself with integers and basic arithmetic is both irresponsible and insane.

Comment: i will try to give an example later, I think MongoDB drivers probably convert the integer in the actually DB to Date objects. I have seen people try to sort dated objects with just the string representation of a date, it was one of the worst things in the coding world that I have ever seen.

Answer (score 3):

If you have strings with date info you can....

```
C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
///...
    comparator: function(m) {
        return -Date.parse(m.get('datestring'));
    }
});
```